# Excel VBA: Insert text from cell within a hyperlink

Tags: google-maps, excel, hyperlink, vba

I'm a newbie on here and have a pretty simple question. I have some lat/long data in Excel that I want to convert to a Google Maps Street View hyperlink. I have looked up on another thread on here how to put the hyperlink together but I'm struggling to work out how to repetitively copy the lat/long data across to the middle of the web address.

I have concatenated my lat/long (decimal) into a single cell as text in the right format (i.e. *lat,long*), which is in column J and want the hyperlink to be in column N, which should read:

http://maps.google.com/?cbll={lat,long from column J}&cbp=12,90,,0,5&layer=c

I have tried looking on some other threads here but can't quite work it out as they're all rather more complex examples. Hopefully someone can help resolve this really easily for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, s4 As String
    s1 = "http://maps.google.com/?cbll={"
    s3 = "}&cbp=12,90,,0,5&layer=c"
    s2 = Range("J1").Text
    s4 = s1 & s2 & s3
    With ActiveSheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("N1"), Address:=s4, TextToDisplay:=s2
    End With
End Sub
```

So that if **J1** contains:

```
51.507351.,-0.127758
```

The result in **N1** would be:

http://maps.google.com/?cbll={51.507351.,-0.127758}&cbp=12,90,,0,5&layer=c

**EDIT#1:**

To run this down column **J,** use this version:

```
Sub dural2()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, s4 As String
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    s1 = "http://maps.google.com/?cbll={"
    s3 = "}&cbp=12,90,,0,5&layer=c"
    For i = 1 To N
        s2 = Range("J" & i).Text
        s4 = s1 & s2 & s3
        With ActiveSheet
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("N" & i), Address:=s4, TextToDisplay:=s2
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!
Could you tell me how I then repeat this over the 300-odd lines? I tried changing "J1" to "J1:J300" but it didn't like it.